# Flutter as GUI on Linux (non-Android)

Tags: linux, flutter

I am thinking about creating a GUI for an embedded system using Flutter/Dart. The system will be a plain non-android system running on ARM.

The GUI will be the only piece of software visible on the screen, so there will be no need for a desktop environment.

I have done this before using QT embedded/C++, but the design requirements for the new device's GUI are such that this approach would be inefficient.

I was wondering if anyone might have succeeded in such an effort and would be willing to share.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding might do what you want or you can use it as inspiration

Comment: I personally haven't tried it yet. This medium article [Flutter on Raspberry Pi (mostly) from scratch](https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-on-raspberry-pi-mostly-from-scratch-2824c5e7dcb1) looks promising. [![Flutter on Raspberry Pi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqExc.jpg?s=256)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqExc.jpg?s=256)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hello @Ber, did you manage to use Flutter on Linux embedded? I'm very interested in doing the same and would love to hear some experiences with this. I am desperately looking for an alternative to QT (and really like Flutter so far) :)

Comment: Hello @Giulia, I didn't have a chance to work on it, so far. However, there was great news on this topic at the latest Google IO, they are extenting Flutter beyond mobile platforms into the Web and on the Desktop. There was even mention of embedded platforms.
I have also seen a couple of articles, posts and how-tos on the subject. I think we should be able to use this great technology in 2020.

Comment: @Ber may I ask if you managed to implement this with flutter, because I am trying to do the same. If you did - can you perhaps post an answer/comment roughly outlining the path you took?

Comment: @voidvoid Sorry, we ended up using AOSP instead of Linux. Hope to do is some day, though.

Answer (score 1):

The official Flutter documentation and examples for building a desktop shell is at:

- https://flutter.dev/desktop

Desktop, embedded system, and web are still experimental and not yet fully supported, but building upon what others have attempted and links shared from the comments, so as mentioned:

- There’s https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding, though some parts have been merged into the main Flutter SDK, others parts are still currently relevant for launching desktop apps, such as [/example/linux](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/example/linux) inside flutter-desktop-embedding/example/.
- Nov 2018, [medium/Flutter on Raspberry Pi (mostly) from scratch](https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-on-raspberry-pi-mostly-from-scratch-2824c5e7dcb1), involves a Flutter engine built for ARMv7 and the embedder as https://github.com/chinmaygarde/flutter_from_scratch.
- And one more, Oct 2019, [medium/Flutter mobile, web and desktop](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-mobile-web-and-desktop-the-stars-race-770d7b8df1b8), most recent and perhaps most useful since it demonstrates across three platforms (though not quite your requirements, since it runs in a desktop environment).

  - but I was able to get this sample running on Chrome and my Linux desktop following this, it will involve  flutter-desktop-embedding/example/linux.

Otherwise, working examples are few and far between.

(there is another [medium/Flutter for Desktop: Create and Run a Desktop Application](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-for-desktop-create-and-run-a-desktop-application-ebeb1604f1e0), but is not recommended because it is based on an even older version, prone to various issues)

Answer (score 1):

Updated 2020:

https://elinux.org/ELC_Europe_2020_Presentations, on the page, search "**Graphical User Interface Using Flutter in Embedded Systems**" for the pdf slides and youtube video.

the companion source code seems to be on https://github.com/sony/flutter-embedded-linux. (very active, should be more progress in 2021)